# Typescript passing values to Date Validation Decorators?

Tags: typescript, class-validator

I'm trying to validate a date like this (Both the purchase date and the receipt date are class properties):

```
@IsDate()
@MinDate(date: this.purchaseDate)
receiptDate: Date;
```

However I get the following errors:

src/main/ts/domain/PurchaseOrder.ts(20,16): error TS1005: ',' expected.
src/main/ts/domain/PurchaseOrder.ts(20,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'date'.

How should the purchase date annotation constraint be passed?  The annotations are from the [class-validator](https://github.com/pleerock/class-validator) library.

Comment: you are using this.purchaseDate as a type. try `@MinDate(this.purchaseDate)`

Comment: That looks like it works!  Thanks.  Please put it as the official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you are using is wrong. It looks like you are half trying to define a function with the type **this.purchaseDate**.

All you have to do is send **this.purchaseDate** as a parameter.

```
@MinDate(this.purchaseDate)
```